# Compressing a bit matrix when receiving the row in random order

Tags: c++, c, cuda, compression, arrays

I am working with an `Nx3` bit matrix where the number of row `N` is very large, say `2^40`.
A typical matrix looks like this

```
000
001
010
011
...
```

I do something like this

```
transform_row(5); //return 000
transform_row(10); //return 101
assemble_array(000,101); 
//return a 10x3 matrix, where:
//row 5: 000
//row 10: 101
//the other rows wait for the other iteration to be filled

...//repeat
```

The bit pattern in both my `initial_matrix` and `transformed_matrix` is either very redundant or very spare. For example, the first column can be only `0` or there can be huge block of `1`.

What are my option for assembling and efficiently compressing in this situation?
Should I roll my own assembling algorithm, or can I use some compression library?
I'm thinking about rolling my own because I don't know if a compression library can work efficiently in this sequential situation.

I'm executing `assemble_array` in parallel on a gpu.
So the function needs to be threads safe, associative and commutative.

bit_matrix_transform.cu

```
bit_matrix initial_matrix;
first=0;
last=2^40;
UnaryFunction bit_vector transform_row::operator(long row_index);
BinaryFunction bit_matrix assemble_array::operator(bit_array x, bit_array y);
bit_matrix transformed_matrix = thrust::transform_reduce(first, last, transform_row, init, assemble_array);
//a bit_array being either a bit_vector or a bit_matrix
```

Comment: If your matrix is sparse, then you could use a sparse matrix representation.  In which case, you could use [Cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/), which is built on top of Thrust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a simple run-length representation of the array, where it is initialized as a run of 2^40 zeros.  (Or if zero is different than empty, use -1 or 8.)  The initial run-length representation would be simply 2^40, 0.  When you insert an element, you break a run into two.  So to put a 111 in position n (starting the count at zero), you get n, 0, 1, 7, 2^40-n-1, 0.  If I insert another 111 adjacent to the first one, I make that a run: n, 0, 2, 7, 2^40-n-2, 0.  And so on.

If there is more correlation at the bit-level than the three-bit level, then do this three times, once for each column of bits.

Comment: Do you know an implementation of the run-length algorithm that can get me started? The algorithm seems straightfoward, but this will ease my first encounter with it.

Comment: No, I have only seen run-length algorithms applied to already-constructed data.  I haven't seen any adaptive run-length code as I have described it.  I probably just invented it.

Comment: You are a great mind. Thank you. I will implement your algorithm.